# The sorting by newest on jobs seems to be broken ... again

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, sorting

Reposting this as it was marked as completed in a prior post

See screenshot. Looks like it is sorting off the formatted date, not timestamp

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me... do you see the order change when you go from the "matches" sort to "newest"?

Comment: @Matt, see this screenshot http://www.screencast.com/t/JLXzGNBL00

Comment: @NickSchild Ok, if that's a *still screenshot* not a video, why the hell do I need Flash installed (I don't) in order to see it? Worst image hosting site ever.